# Description of columns in a DB2 table

Tags: sql, db2

How can we know the description of every column in a table(DB2) through SQL?

My data base is DB2.

Answer (score 23):

```
select 
  tabname,
  colname,
  typename,
  length,
  scale,
  default,
  nulls,
  identity,
  generated,
  remarks,
  keyseq 
from 
  syscat.columns
```

Answer (score 20):

```
SELECT 
TABLE_CAT, 
TABLE_SCHEM, 
TABLE_NAME, 
COLUMN_NAME, 
DATA_TYPE, 
TYPE_NAME, 
COLUMN_SIZE, 
COLUMN_TEXT
FROM "SYSIBM"."SQLCOLUMNS"
WHERE TABLE_SCHEM = 'SCHEMA' 
 AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE'
```

This is on DB2 V5R4, and is not a System Table but a `SYSTEM VIEW`. In case that you go nuts looking for it on the tables list.

Comment: Just FYI, the table and schema names are case sensitive.  Hopefully that will save some people some time.

Answer (score 12):

-- NOTE: the where clause is case sensitive and needs to be uppercase

```
select
t.table_schema as Library
,t.table_name
,t.table_type
,c.column_name
,c.ordinal_position
,c.data_type
,c.character_maximum_length as Length
,c.numeric_precision as Precision
,c.numeric_scale as Scale
,c.column_default
,t.is_insertable_into
from sysibm.tables t
join sysibm.columns c
on t.table_schema = c.table_schema
and t.table_name = c.table_name
where t.table_schema = 'MYLIB'
and t.table_name = 'MYTABLE'
order by t.table_name, c.ordinal_position
```

-- to get a list of all the meta tables:

```
select * from sysibm.tables
where table_schema = 'SYSIBM'
```

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT COLNAME, REMARKS 
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
WHERE TABSCHEMA = 'MYSCHEMA'
AND TABNAME = 'MYTABLENAME'`

Answer (score 2):

```
describe table schema.table_name ;
```

[**DB2 Describe Command**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/core/r0002019.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I work on an iSeries DB2 box (v5r4), it is a special flavor of DB2.

If you're on or connecting to an iSeries (AS/400), the link mentioned by Anton is most excellent (sorry, can't vote yet!)

Describe does not work on an iSeries, but will work with DB2 on the other platforms.

Comment: V6R1 is out! If you have access to the data provider DLL, it now implements ADO.NET 2.0 (DbProviderFactory, etc). It's backwards compatible with V5R4.

Answer (score 2):

```
select T1.name,T1.creator from sysibm.systables T1,sysibm.syscolumns 
T2 where T1.name=T2.tbname and T1.creator=T2.tbccreator and 
T1.creator='CREATOR NAME' and T2.name='COLUMN NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
select * from sysibm.columns
where table_schema = 'MY_SCHEMA'
```