# Perl DBI: store the ddl of a column in a variable

Tags: perl, db2, dbi

In Perl DBI, can I store the ddl of a column in a variable? My objective, is to use the definition of the column to create a temp table in another database.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Most database have tables about table info, or meta data. Looks like you are using DB2, so here is an example [Description of columns in a DB2 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580735/description-of-columns-in-a-db2-table)

You could also copy part of a table to a temporary table.

Comment: Hi Kim, In fact I'm using the db2 driver in dbi. So, if I create a table a temp table in perl DBI on database A, how can I extract the temp table definition to create the same temp table on database B?

Comment: Just use the SQL "create table as" syntax and it is remade with the same data definitions. I think this should be OK for DB2:

 CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.NEW_TB AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM SCHEMA.OLD_TB
) WITH NO DATA

Comment: The 2 different databases are on 2 different servers. The temp table definition on Database A is not visible on database B. So, I need to use the Perl to store the definition and reuse it.

Comment: Perhaps export the table definition as an SQL CREATE TABLE statement. Then run this statement on Database B to make your temp table.

Answer (score -1):

The simple method is to get the description of the table and then parsing it might yield the ddl of the desired column.

Considering, the description of the table is stored in a file 'table.txt',

```
$cat table.txt
 Name                                     Null?    Type
 -------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COLUMN1                                NOT NULL DATE
 COLUMN2                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(31)
 COLUMN3                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)
 COLUMN4                                NOT NULL NUMBER



#!/usr/bin/perl
open (FILE, 'table.txt');
while (my $line = <FILE>)
{
  chomp($line);
  $line =~ s/\s\s+/,/g;
  $line =~ s/NULL /NULL,/gi;
  my ($column,$null_field,$type) = split /,/, $line, 3;
  print "$column $type $null_field,\n";
}
close (FILE);
```

P.S: The first two lines of 'table.txt' needs to be ignored as they constitute the header information.